# Formulating a linear programming problem

Tags: linear-programming

I have the following problem:

[image]

Now I would like someone to verify whether my answer is correct or not :) Here goes:
If I denote the different alloys by $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$ I get

$$\text{minimize}\;\;\;5x_1+4x_2+3x_3+2x_4+ 1.5x_5$$
$$\text{subject to}\;\;\; 10x_1+25x_2+50x_3+75x_4+95x_5 = 0.3$$
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; 90x_1+75x_2+50x_3+25x_4+5x_5 = 0.7$$

I'm not sure whether I did this one correct or not. Any verifications? :)

Thank you!

Comment: It looks alright to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suppositions and expressions are right. Just solve it.

Comment: @jjepsuomi you are welcome

Comment: oh, sorry. Yes I just accepted, I couldn't before because there was the time limit :)